# Gray code on N symbols

Tags: code-golf, coding-theory

A [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is a permutation on binary numbers where incrementing or decrementing a number only ever causes a single bit to change. For example, a Gray code for the binary numbers up to 7 (so, with 3 bits) are:

```
000
001
011
010
110
111
101
100
```

You can see that only one bit is different between each consecutive pair.

This is only one valid 3-bit Gray code; others are possible by permuting the columns or reversing the list.

An [\$ N \$-ary Gray Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary) is a generalised Gray code which operates on \$ N \$ symbols instead of just two. For example, a Gray code with \$ N = 3 \$, and of length 2:

```
00
01
02
12
11
10
20
21
22
```

Note that a single digit can change up or down by more than one from one step to the next. For example, the following **is allowed**: (as a partial output for \$ N = 4 \$, \$ k = 3 \$)

```
001
003
```

Here is another possible output, which is also allowed:

```
21
22
20
00
10
11
01
02
12
```

### Task

Given two integers, \$ N \$ and \$ k \$, output an \$ N \$-ary Gray code of length \$ k \$.

You may output using any consistent set of \$ N \$ distinct symbols; they don't necessarily have to be digits or integers.

You may assume both \$ N \ge 2 \$ and \$ k \ge 2 \$.

There are multiple orderings for all inputs; you only need to output at least one of these, but you may output multiple.

### Test cases

I list only one possible output for each.

```
N  k  output
2  2  00, 01, 11, 10
3  2  00, 01, 02, 12, 11, 10, 20, 21, 22
2  3  000, 001, 011, 010, 110, 111, 101, 100
5  2  00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 20, 21, 22, 32, 33, 34, 30, 31, 41, 42, 43, 44, 40
4  4  0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0013, 0010, 0011, 0012, 0022, 0023, 0020, 0021, 0031, 0032, 0033, 0030, 0130, 0131, 0132, 0133, 0103, 0100, 0101, 0102, 0112, 0113, 0110, 0111, 0121, 0122, 0123, 0120, 0220, 0221, 0222, 0223, 0233, 0230, 0231, 0232, 0202, 0203, 0200, 0201, 0211, 0212, 0213, 0210, 0310, 0311, 0312, 0313, 0323, 0320, 0321, 0322, 0332, 0333, 0330, 0331, 0301, 0302, 0303, 0300, 1300, 1301, 1302, 1303, 1313, 1310, 1311, 1312, 1322, 1323, 1320, 1321, 1331, 1332, 1333, 1330, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1003, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1012, 1013, 1010, 1011, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1020, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1133, 1130, 1131, 1132, 1102, 1103, 1100, 1101, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1110, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1213, 1223, 1220, 1221, 1222, 1232, 1233, 1230, 1231, 1201, 1202, 1203, 1200, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2203, 2213, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2222, 2223, 2220, 2221, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2230, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2303, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2312, 2313, 2310, 2311, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2320, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2033, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2123, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2132, 2133, 2130, 2131, 2101, 2102, 2103, 2100, 3100, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3113, 3110, 3111, 3112, 3122, 3123, 3120, 3121, 3131, 3132, 3133, 3130, 3230, 3231, 3232, 3233, 3203, 3200, 3201, 3202, 3212, 3213, 3210, 3211, 3221, 3222, 3223, 3220, 3320, 3321, 3322, 3323, 3333, 3330, 3331, 3332, 3302, 3303, 3300, 3301, 3311, 3312, 3313, 3310, 3010, 3011, 3012, 3013, 3023, 3020, 3021, 3022, 3032, 3033, 3030, 3031, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3000
11 2  0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 0 4, 0 5, 0 6, 0 7, 0 8, 0 9, 0 10, 1 10, 1 0, 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 5, 1 6, 1 7, 1 8, 1 9, 2 9, 2 10, 2 0, 2 1, 2 2, 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, 2 6, 2 7, 2 8, 3 8, 3 9, 3 10, 3 0, 3 1, 3 2, 3 3, 3 4, 3 5, 3 6, 3 7, 4 7, 4 8, 4 9, 4 10, 4 0, 4 1, 4 2, 4 3, 4 4, 4 5, 4 6, 5 6, 5 7, 5 8, 5 9, 5 10, 5 0, 5 1, 5 2, 5 3, 5 4, 5 5, 6 5, 6 6, 6 7, 6 8, 6 9, 6 10, 6 0, 6 1, 6 2, 6 3, 6 4, 7 4, 7 5, 7 6, 7 7, 7 8, 7 9, 7 10, 7 0, 7 1, 7 2, 7 3, 8 3, 8 4, 8 5, 8 6, 8 7, 8 8, 8 9, 8 10, 8 0, 8 1, 8 2, 9 2, 9 3, 9 4, 9 5, 9 6, 9 7, 9 8, 9 9, 9 10, 9 0, 9 1, 10 1, 10 2, 10 3, 10 4, 10 5, 10 6, 10 7, 10 8, 10 9, 10 10, 10 0
```

### Rules

- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- For compactness in the test-cases, when \$ N \le 10 \$, I've squished the output digits together. However, your output format must always have an unambiguous separation of the digits when \$ N > 10 \$
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24542)

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164558/78410)

Comment: Is the output required to start with `0...0`?

Comment: Can we output all possibilities?

Comment: @emanresuA Yes, as long as you don't output duplicates

Comment: @alephalpha Not necessarily; the symbol `0` has no special meaning

Comment: Are leading `0`s required?

Comment: May we use 1-based symbols? So for \$N=3\$ we use `1,2,3` instead of `0,1,2`?

Comment: @Neil That was already asked by _alephalpha_ in the comments above (and the answer is no, it's optional).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Actually I understood his question has having an entirely different meaning, i.e. is it allowed to start the code on any `k` digits, not just all `0`s.

Comment: @Neil Ah, you're indeed correct! I see I've misread his comment.

Comment: @Arnauld not sure how I missed that, thanks!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen To clarify exactly: as I already said in the question, the symbols don't have to be integers \$ [0, N) \$.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You also don't have to start at `000` (or `xxx` or whatever symbols you're using) , you can start at `012` as long as each neighbouring pair has only one changed symbol. I've hopefully clarified this

Comment: @pxeger - last test case `10 2` should be `11 2`?

Comment: @kjs yep, sorry. Fixed

Comment: Suggest: *This is only one **of the** valid 3-bit Gray code**s***. Otherwise reads a bit like it's the only valid one.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen As it happens, I've golfed down my leading-zeros-included answer to the same length as my leading-zeros-omitted answer, so it no longer matters.

Answer (score 10):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 12 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Based on an algorithm [given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code). Takes `k` as left and `N` as right argument.

```
⊢|-⟜»¨∘⥊∘↕∘⥊
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqifC3in5zCu8Ko4oiY4qWK4oiY4oaV4oiY4qWKCgpyZXN1bHRzIOKGkCDin6gKMiBGy5wgMgozIEbLnCAyCjIgRsucIDMKNSBGy5wgMgo0IEbLnCA0CjEwIEbLnCAyCuKfqQoKIyBBc3NlcnQgYWxsIHJlc3VsdHMgYXJlIHZhbGlkIGdyYXkgY29kZXM6CklzR3JheSDihpAgeyjwnZWp4omh4o238J2VqSniiKfCtDE9K8udy5h8w5ctwrTLmDLihpXwnZWpfQoh4oinwrQgSXNHcmF5wqggcmVzdWx0cwoK4oiY4oC/MeKlinJlc3VsdHMK)

`⥊∘↕∘⥊` Generate a list of all base-`N` numbers of length `k`.
Then each number is transformed to Gray code, lets look at an example:

```
N=3, k=3, number is 2 1 2
-⟜»                   # Shift a 0 into the number and subtract that from the number.
2 1 2 - 0 2 1 → 2 ¯1 1
⊢|                    # modulo N; This relies on Python-like modulo, otherwise you might need to add N before
3 | 2 ¯1 1    → 2 2 1
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```
{k  n:
  n|{-»}¨⥊↕k⥊n
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
ʁÞẊṖ'¯:fTl
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgcOe4bqK4bmWJ8KvOmZUbCIsIiIsIjNcbjIiXQ==)

```
   Ṗ'      # Find all permutations of...
 ÞẊ        # Cartesian power of input and...
ʁ          # Range(input)
    '      # Where...
     ¯     # Differences (vectorising)
      :  l # Length is unchanged when...
       fT  # Flattening and getting truthy indices.
```

Comment: Is `_:fTl` a sufficient condition for being a valid Gray code?

Comment: @pxeger For it to accept a change of multiple symbols there would also have to be a change of no symbols, but the words should be unique already.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗ@Ż€I%
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the length, \$k\$, on the left and the number of symbols, \$N\$ on the right and yields a list of lists of non-negative integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzukOR3c/alrjqfr//3/j/6YA)**

#### How?

This is the same cyclic Gray code that the algorithm displayed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) will produce (for values \$[1,N^k]+[0]\$) with each result reversed.

```
ṗ@Ż€I% - Link: k, N
 @     - with swapped arguments:
ṗ      -   [1..N] Cartesian product [1..k]
  Ż€   - prefix a zero to each
    I  - incremental differences
     % - modulo N
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 45 bytes

```
Mod[#-{0,##&@@Most@#}&/@Range@#~Tuples~#2,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RchLCsIwFEbhrVz4IaMUa4pD5W6gINJZyCBoqgX7wKajS7r1aEVwdPhO7@Mj9D52V59bOuZ6vFkUUmpAMdfjHBlJ7fjih3tgrM0yPcO8wmg4lc@vbohWgETFiVoLOEeKmJlEjCaTNEn168fV1sP/f70vt5HyGw)

A port of [@ovs's BQN answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243887/9288).

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

```
IntegerDigits[FindHamiltonianPath@GridGraph@Table@##-1,##]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxCsIwEEB/5eCgUwq2xVG5QaxuHdxCh9Om7UETJWYL/faYiuD0eI9nOczGcpAHpxEO6eqCmYw/ySThrc/ihgtbWcLTCbsuz9R6GVrPr5lufF8MIZaVQuyL1HlxQUfEFcojjDrHHgogIoixVlCvCmLzY/Zm4/7fv17ttrCmDw)

Finds a Hamiltonian path of the \$\underbrace{N\times\cdots\times N}_{k}\$ grid graph.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LIãε0š¥¹%
```

-1 byte porting [*@ovs*' BQN answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243887/52210), using the approach [described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code).

Inputs in the order \$N,k\$. Outputs a single result using 0-based integers in the range \$[0,N)\$, like the challenge description.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx/Pw4nNbDY4uPLT00E7V//@NuYwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@ZUKzkZ3t4v45CNpBU0uFS8i8tAUoC5XSAcodW/vcpPrz43FaDowsPLT20TvV/rc6hbfb/o6ONdIxidaKNwaSRjjGQNAWzTXRMgKShIZATCwA).

**Original <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
LIãœʒü-ĀOP
```

Inputs in the order \$N,k\$. Outputs using 1-based integers in the range \$[1,N]\$, and will output all possible results (and is very slow because of that).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx/Pw4qOTT006vEf3SIN/wP//xlxGAA) or [verify some of the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@ZUKzkZ3t4v45CNpBU0uFS8i8tAUoC5XSAcv99ig8vPjpZ79yUw3t0jzT4B/yv1Tm0zf5/dLSRjlGsTrQxmDTSMY6NBQA) (with the filter `ʒ` replaced with a find_first `.Δ` to speed things up a bit).

**Explanation:**

```python
L           # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input N]
 Iã         # Get the second input k's cartesian product of this list
   ε        # Map over each inner k-tuple:
    0š      #  Prepend a 0
      ¥     #  Pop and push the deltas/forward-differences
       ¹%   #  Modulo-N on each value
            # (after which the list of lists is output implicitly as result)

LIã         # Same as above
   œ        # Get all possible permutations of these k-tuples
    ʒ       # Filter this list of permutations by:
     ü      #  For each overlapping k-tuple:
      -     #   Subtract the values at the same positions in the tuples
       Ā    #  Check for each that it's NOT 0 (0 if 0; 1 otherwise)
        O   #  Sum to get the amount of values that differ per overlapping pair
         P  #  Get the product of these sums
            #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, so only the permutations where each
            #  overlapping k-tuple has a single value different are kept)
            # (after which the filtered list of k-tuple permutations is output
            # implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>82</s>  78 bytes

Expects `(N)(k)`.

```javascript
N=>k=>[...Array(N**k)].map(g=(s=i=k,v)=>i--?[x=~~(s+v/N**i)%N,...g(s-x,v)]:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lcy7DoIwFIDh3acgJibncKnh4mJyMK4OODgiA0FoKkhJSwgsvDo2PoCB/fv/dz7kulCi671WvsqloiWhuKY4ZYxdlconSGy7xox98g44gSZBtTsgxcLzLulI8wzaGY5GCTwkrsk4aG80JDunGS6FbLVsStZIDrfHPWG6V6LlopqgAitACBAtx9o/2z3u/uNwCzbncDU@bTlHCNFa7Pu/My5f)

#### Commented

This is based on [the algorithm given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code).

```javascript
N =>                       // N = number of symbols
k =>                       // k = code length
[...Array(N ** k)]         // build an array of N ** k entries
.map(g = (                 // g is a recursive callback function taking:
    s =                    //   s = step     \__ initially set to k
    i = k,                 //   i = position /
                           //   NB: we should start with s = 0, but since
                           //       we're working modulo N, it actually
                           //       doesn't matter
    v                      //   v = current value in [0 .. N ** k - 1]
  ) =>                     //
  i-- ?                    //   decrement i; if it was not 0:
    [                      //     update the output:
      x =                  //       define x as:
        ~~(s + v / N ** i) //         floor(s + v / N ** i)
        % N,               //         modulo N
      ...g(s - x, v)       //       append the result of a recursive call
                           //       with s - x and v unchanged
    ]                      //     end of output update
  :                        //   else:
    []                     //     stop the recursion
)                          // end of map()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＩＥＸθηＥ÷ιＸθ⮌…⁰η⌊﹪⟦⊖±λλ⟧⊗θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYs9D4MgFEX3/grGZ0KTDm6OZXHQGFfTAeFFSPhQBPvzKaRJ07ude88Vigfhucm5d3uKY7IrBjia7vbPqvAUtIvw5GeEge8w@XcVKVENJbXoXWT60hJBU/JbZ7wwnAgzdxvCo@ol5aGdtsnC4GUyHhaGIqBFF1HCiBuPCKZ65kUJ82k1pT@ab7qcW9Lm@2U@) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs each digit of the gray code as a base 10 number on its own line, with each gray code double-spaced from the next. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                              Input `N` as a number
  Ｎη                            Input `k` as a number
       θ                        Input `N`
      Ｘ                         To the power of
        η                       Input `k`
     Ｅ                          Map over implicit range
           ι                    Current value
          ÷                     Vectorised integer divide
             θ                  Input `N`
            Ｘ                   Vectorised to power
               …                Range from
                ⁰               Literal integer `0`
                 η              To input `k`
              ⮌                 Reversed
         Ｅ                      Map over list
                       λ        Current value
                      ±         Negated
                     ⊖          Decremented
                    ⟦    ⟧      List of that and
                        λ       Current value
                   ﹪            Vectorised modulo
                           θ    Input `N`
                          ⊗     Doubled
                  ⌊             Take the minimum
    Ｉ                           Cast to string
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

Uses `[1..N]` for the digits.

```hs
n!0=[[]]
n!k=[a:x|a<-[1..n],x<-iterate reverse(n!(k-1))!!a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BasMwEETv@ooxhCCBnMZpeil2T6Wl0N4CPRhRNkQQEVk2klzckn93JWrIaXfe7s7smcJFWzubbuh9xDNF2rybEMHdeBSzK7ZN2yrFXHFpWnqcrlSXbbXZOCWnujRRe4oaXn9rHzR3Bb@UlRBFQWo@9r099G8u4uBHjQYVu6EXsiGzLWMmvHr6wZRUDs1Ng0lgvQa5E9oq6zB24LfzevWEXzN8mnjmd40A4ShwBSeZal3mGXgkY7PRpBjryLgUcOrBAKtjejmMNobEFh/wQqDdyXu5kw9yL6utyvIf7OVOpcPBmxS@AlmL5e3FJw07Gj6@lpWFzn8)

This uses a simple recursive construction: Given the Gray code for `k-1`, alternate between this and its reverse for each of the new digits.
`iterate reverse x !! a` reverses `x` for odd `a` (and can probably be shortened). The approach is described in more detail [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code).

The other approach is a byte longer:

```hs
n!k=map(`mod`n).(zipWith(-)<*>(0:))<$>mapM(\_->[1..n])[1..k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9Bb4MwDIXv/IpXqaqSKbDCuksFnDrtsp13YKh1BVMjkoBIkNi0/86SjZ1sv2d/tm9ku1apReqhHx1O5Ch5kdaBmenKF7PpCk0Du@i@uRiesC85vEl3YzHP70q2P3Keb0vf8crez3FZpUliah5CVy/SPo/0iRnFLy0kBWaO3Q5kGlRpqO2kwT7GXj8Zn3kY/lfcFxyEK8c3GAkf8zh4YI6kCpy5jiJN0nh@0yMCVOswtnZSznpt5YBtOKpMPIhMPIqDSPd1KP@Eg8hqPziM0jhsQUphvXrleDN8d15bVnX5AQ)

The part left of `<$>` can be either `` zipWith(((`mod`n).).(-))<*>(0:) `` or `zipWith(\a b->mod(a-b)n)<*>(0:)` at no byte difference.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>163</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>149</s></sup> 146 bytes

```c
s;w;i;p;*f(n,k){int*g=calloc(p=pow(n,k),4*k),b[p*k];for(;p--;){for(w=p,i=0;s=w;w/=n)b[p*k+i++]=w%n;for(;i--;s+=n-g[w])g[w]=(b[w=p*k+i]+s)%n;}s=g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3ZfdbuJWFEbv8xRWpBnxYzTee2N@6qJeVH2KDBoRD0kJGYJCJKJGvHrTs8/xMpCh6n0jzeaM/X1m2SyQXQ/u6/r9fVftq1W1rXp3nU2@7r6tNi@9@1m9eHx8qjvb2fZpH7fnw14Ytzfb3npe3T09d6rtYFB133y5n23z1ayodrN9tf8y23RjrL/q9@ez/adNiq9CfNefbQb3N/t518esc3sTqp6c93fdEDzsZvfV4T0gZD8Wq02nm71dZeHPN7wsdy/fNjfzbJa9aZ5ZnoVZ5tkwz0QO1Xlu3ebaaMjpSWz5ul3WL8vvkpJFXoTjpCF5VuRyIasfs5pGKjRVyeO7qm@79IZ2PEhzmOZNi3SU5qU5nKRIfIfLUMOLUOZjmMYZXqS1NOJVSaCn3Jqb7zXfa77XfG8cfhF9mI@hjyIfXoAqT0@yPc0GrgCwWTTXoMjPLkZzZZuFElbCSrhdGGEjbIRPFkJYCAthAaz5FArCRd5eWQFMgD/5yAo@tAZMgBfgBfh2oYSVsBJWwBR4BV6BV8Daj12BV@AVsNZXBV6BbxdG2AgbYQPMgDfgDXgDzIA34A14A8yAN@AN@JOFEBbCQlgAE@AFeAFeABPgBXgBXgAT4AV4AV4QSZBNkE2QTRC7@cIWwBfAF4AVwBfAt1/SArAC@AL4Avh20f7oCGEhLIAJ8AK8AC@ACfDS/tocf33aXyNBfkF@QX5BJEE2QTZBNkFsQX5BfkF@QWxBfkF@QX5BbEF@QX5B/nahhJWwElbAFHgFXoFXwBR4BV6BV8AUeAVegVdEUmRTZFNkU8RW5FfkV@RXxFbkV@RX5FfEVuRX5FfkV0RSZFNkU2RTxFbkV@RX5FfEVuRX5FfkV8RW5FfkV@RXRFJkU2RTZFPEVuRX5FfkV8RW5FfkV@RXxFbkV@RX5G8XRtgIG2EDzIA34A14A8yAN@ANeAPMgDfgDXhDJEM2QzZDNkNsQ35DfkN@Q2xDfkN@Q35DbEN@Q35DfkMkQzZDNkM2Q2xDfkN@Q35DbEN@Q35DfkNsQ35DfkN@QyRDNkM2QzZDbEN@Q35DfkNsQ35DfkN@Q2xDfkN@Q367cF80@o@btdLHyMfYx8THNIaLZv7LzVy8yyt9jHyMfUx8TNPQWP75Xu94E1j6GPkY@5ikYV62WD67Ffxwj1j6GPkYpzH08tDLw1hOd4qXbyFLH6M0Si@XXi69XMZy6WVf@lAflsc7/9LLcYy8PPLyyMsjL49ieeRlX/pQH@ZjmMbYy2Mvj7089vLYy@NYHnvZlz7Uh6Ux8fLEyxMvT7w88fLEy5NYnnjZlz40jamXp16eennq5amXp16eenkay1Mv@zINSfdi6UYs3dVHXST6IlEYicZIVEYaW9JNXXFUsde6mFRsn4Py42POcWnH5fC4LI/LUXPk@mmze8nqPxfPvTCX9Xr5nI5//fX1D/36Ov09/Cuv8@z0/3bdtMMDYtbx78lq8335GmpF1Sx/zXarv5ZPdx3esPul2dBrt1RZvx/T3Xiw9MjIN28TjtY8OsbMvDrbvWb3@uLu3iLsTw/GH3Ysw472Sl6qbhe7XcjI@dbbsIlH6uOe9vwf0rk/hPO@9dN66J6czlmyTsk6JNeerD8m/W/7HKJ3netPu0/fw7Wvf/MP4Jfrt/CyuHkID971/ISibSXy@PL5c5vMZuGMm/V56XB16U0P2XU4@NXPoSPV141TNbr4@53iEBv8T//CyZ8q8LxcdhbNhsPV4f3v@u5xcb97H@zfB48//gE)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs two integers \$N\$ and \$k\$.
Returns a pointer to a (flattened) \$N\$-ary Gray code of length \$k\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 94 bytes

```perl
sub g{($N,$k)=@_;--$k?do{@a=g($N,$k);map{//;map[$',@$_],@a=reverse@a}0..$N-1}:map[$_],0..$N-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHfb4IwEMefx19R3WlBiwrqi6SzL3tlia/MEIxIGAKm1RlD@NvdtbCNNFzvx/fT6/WSyvP6@VS3A8kaG0IGhcNFHLguFNtj3YiEZ304KJNLM59rEwFlAuI9w7RMv1OpUpG0i9kMQtdrN6YCs78Bg89VnMnkQZryAamUwamWtjrnx7zK7Ehgte84mLMhYXDAHiAOdN2Uq1tpIxEg0dAqBTj80V8hcQbcawe6tLX0OT2TGJZicDf3QQCJBChUoiyewt319ntGEIJRF@69@FaaBlUAasohJtglqkG1lu438pmPomjZGZ8ttVl33oqttPE8dJ3GIvjpFvqR4nX6EBHnXF3/x2rCF5lX1xMZjhQ6IUdTcLMfqc9qyKyXfny2ETvjcQfhEE4m@FK0LuiGvu92HzuKxUgmUODmq84rmzKCS0/AuHjum7fYUoIK6uh3xJ@hBlb7/AE)